# RealmSwift + ObjectMapper managing String Array (tags)

Tags: swift, realm, objectmapper

What I need to represent in RealmSwift is the following JSON scheme:

```
{ 
    "id": 1234,
    "title": "some value",
    "tags": [ "red", "blue", "green" ]
}
```

Its a basic string array that I'm stumbling on. I'm guessing in Realm I need to represent "tags" as

```
dynamic id: Int = 0
dynamic title: String = ""
let tags = List<MyTagObject>()
```

making tags its own table in Realm, but how to map it with ObjectMapper? This is how far I got...

```
func mapping(map: Map) {
    id <- map["id"]
    title <- map["title"]
    tags <- map["tags"]
}
```

... but the tags line doesn't compile of course because of the List and Realm cannot use a [String] type.

This feels like a somewhat common problem and I'm hoping someone who has faced this can comment or point to a post with a suggestion.

**UPDATE 1**
The MyTagObject looks like the following:

```
class MyTagObject: Object {
    dynamic var name: String = ""
}
```

**UPDATE 2**
I found this post which deals with the realm object but assumes the array has named elements rather than a simple string.
https://gist.github.com/Jerrot/fe233a94c5427a4ec29b

Comment: what does `MyTagObject` class look like?

Comment: I updated the question with the class ozgur

Comment: I don't know what is the problem. tag is a list of 'MyTagbject' so this should works fine...

Answer (score 4):

My solution is to use an ObjectMapper `TransformType` as a custom method to map the JSON to a Realm `List<String>` type. No need for 2 Realm models.

Going with your example JSON:

```
{ 
    "id": 1234,
    "title": "some value",
    "tags": [ "red", "blue", "green" ]
}
```

1. First, create an ObjectMapper `TransformType` object:

```swift
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper
import RealmSwift

public struct StringArrayTransform: TransformType {

    public init() { }

    public typealias Object = List<String>
    public typealias JSON = [String]

    public func transformFromJSON(_ value: Any?) -> List<String>? {
        guard let value = value else {
            return nil
        }
        let objects = value as! [String] 
        let list = List<String>()
        list.append(objectsIn: objects)
        return list
    }

    public func transformToJSON(_ value: Object?) -> JSON? {
        return value?.toArray()
    }

}
```

2. Create your 1 Realm model used to store the JSON data:

```swift
import Foundation
import RealmSwift
import ObjectMapper

class MyObjectModel: Object, Mappable {

    @objc dynamic id: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic title: String = ""
    let tags = List<MyTagObject>()

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }    

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id <- map["id"]
        title <- map["title"]
        tags <- (map["tags"], StringArrayTransform())
    }

}
```

Done!

This line is the magic: `tags <- (map["tags"], StringArrayTransform())`. This tells ObjectMapper to use our custom `StringArrayTransform` I showed above which takes the JSON String array and transforms it into a Realm `List<String>`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all we should assume that our model extends both `Object` and `Mappable`.

Let's create a wrapper model to store the primitive (`String`) type:

```
class StringObject: Object {
    dynamic var value = ""
}
```

Then we describe corresponding properties and mapping rules for the root model (not the wrapper one):

```
var tags = List<StringObject>()

var parsedTags: [String] {
    var result = [String]()
    for tag in tags {
        result.append(tag.value)
    }
    return result
}

override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
    return ["parsedTags"]
}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    if let unwrappedTags = map.JSON["tags"] as? [String] {
        for tag in unwrappedTags {
            let tagObject = StringObject()
            tagObject.value = tag
            tags.append(tagObject)
        }
    }
}
```

We need a `tags` property to store and obtain the data about tags from Realm.
Then a `parsedTags` property simplifies extraction of tags in the usual array format.
An `ignoredProperties` definition allows to avoid some failures with Realm while data savings (because of course we can't store non-Realm datatypes in the Realm).
And at last we are manually parsing our tags in the `mapping` function to store it in the Realm.

Answer (score 1):

It will work if your tags array will contains a Dictionary objects with a key: "name"

```
{ 
    "id": 1234,
    "title": "some value",
    "tags": [ ["name" : "red"], ... ]
}
```

If you cannot modify JSON object, I recommend you to map json to realm programmatically.

```
for tagName in tags {
    let tagObject = MyTagObject()
    tagObject.name = tagName
    myObject.tags.append(tagObject)
}
```

Comment: Exactly!! The format cannot be changed, so how do I code that? Is there an example out there?

Comment: `for tagName in tags {
    let tagObject = MyTagObject()
    tagObject.name = tagName
    myObject.tags.append(tagObject)
}`

Comment: I assume that is inside the mapping function, but how do I get "tags" in your for-loop example?

Comment: use a parse library. Like SwiftyJSON

Comment: oh, you mean don't use ObjectMapper at all... write my own custom parsing.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow this code**

```
import ObjectMapper
import RealmSwift

//Create a Model Class
class RSRestaurants:Object, Mappable {

    @objc dynamic var status: String?
    var data = List<RSData>()
    
    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }
    
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        status <- map["status"]
        data <- (map["data"], ListTransform<RSData>())
    }
}

//Use this for creating Array
class ListTransform<T:RealmSwift.Object> : TransformType where T:Mappable {
    typealias Object = List<T>
    typealias JSON = [AnyObject]
    
    let mapper = Mapper<T>()
    
    func transformFromJSON(_ value: Any?) -> Object? {
        let results = List<T>()
        if let objects = mapper.mapArray(JSONObject: value) {
            for object in objects {
                results.append(object)
            }
        }
        return results
    }
    
    func transformToJSON(_ value: Object?) -> JSON? {
        var results = [AnyObject]()
        if let value = value {
            for obj in value {
                let json = mapper.toJSON(obj)
                results.append(json as AnyObject)
            }
        }
        return results
    }
}
```